# Must the object be the same one when using ObjectOutputStream() in java?

Tags: java, sockets

I defined an object "User" in server and client end. The "User" in server end only has a constructor and getter and setter, but the one in client end has some other method.

My project structure is following:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTcTr.jpg)

The code is following:

The server:

```
class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private String password;
private String role;

User(String name, String password, String role) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setPassword(password);
    this.setRole(role);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public String toString() {
    return this.name + this.password + this.role;
}
}
```

The client:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private String password;
private String role;

User(String name, String password, String role) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;

}

/*=====================getter and setter========================*/

public void set(String name, String password, String role) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;

}
public String get() {
    return this.name + " " + this.password + " " + this.role;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public String getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

/*==================Method===================*/

public void showMenu(String title) {

}
}
```

And I want to send a User object from client to server. But an ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pers.yangxujie.RecordMangerServer.main.User
```

Why? Do I have to user the same "User" object?(But I have to define them in both ends, because it is c/s model)

Comment: Are your `User` classes located at the same package at both applications?

Comment: The .class file for the User class must on the classpath for the server so it can call its no-args constructer.

Comment: Please show the complete stacktrace so that we can figure out what is going on here.

Comment: oh...I have added the project structure.

Comment: @lifeisamoive You state above that they are both in the same package, but under my answer you state that they are different. If the comment above is incorrect please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have shown us, I think that the problem is that there is no class called `pers.yangxujie.RecordMangerServer.main.User` on the classpath on the server side.

If the problem was due to differences in the versions of the class on the client and server side, then I would expect to see different exceptions.  It is (IMO) generally a bad idea to use different versions of a class when serializing and deserializing, because the differences can cause all sorts of problems (if you are not careful).  However, sometimes this is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

The class should be *the same* on both ends. Not different classes with the same name. Here 'same' means same name, same package, same `serialVersionUID`.

If you *really* know what you're doing, the classes can have minor disagreements about their fields, subject to the provisions of the Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification: this can be handy as a solution to a deployment problem where you can't update server and client at the same time.

However it doesn't make sense to set out from the beginning to have two different classes called User in the same system. In this case it strongly appears that they are in different packages, which makes them different classes. This will not work for Serialization purposes.

Comment: Yes, they are in different packages. Do you mean the "User" class must be in the same package? You say, "it doesn't make sense to set out from the beginning to have two different classes called User in the same system".  But how to use the same User class in client and server(in two machines)?

Comment: In the same package. Period. Organise your project(s) accordingly. You may have to construct a third project that contains all the shared classes,

Comment: It seems that the structure of my project has some problems. I must rethink it and then refactor it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Is the server class in its own separate file? Make sure neither one of them is an inner class